# 30-45 second response on intitial call to Docker Node app hosted on Google Compute Engine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, google-container-registry

Hard to summarize in the title, but I have a very basic Express app using Docker (`FROM node:latest`) up on Google Compute Engine. The image is hosted in the container registry. I have a compute instance group and template implemented, and I'm using a load balancer with min: 2, max: 4 instances. Health checks are good. I can reach out to my server using the domain I have attached and all routes work as expected.

The issue is, every time I let the server "cool down" for about 20-30 minutes by not sending any traffic to it from outside sources, the instance seems to sort of "go to sleep" and the initial call to warm it back up takes about 45 seconds to get a response.

After the initial call, all subsequent calls take the expected amount of time (a couple of milliseconds). I was planning to use this server in production but I envision every once in a while someone getting caught with one of these long calls and giving up. Has anyone run into this issue before? What would be causing this slow initial request? Below are some screenshots of my GCP settings, as well as my `dockerfile`:

[image: instances]

[image: group]

[image: template]

[image: lb]

```
FROM node:latest

ENV DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive

ENV appDir /var/www/app

RUN mkdir -p /var/www/app
WORKDIR ${appDir}

COPY package*.json /var/www/app/

# Install needed deps and clean up after
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install -y -q --no-install-recommends \
    apt-transport-https \
    build-essential \
    ca-certificates \
    curl \
    g++ \
    gcc \
    git \
    make \
    nginx \
    sudo \
    wget \
    locales \
    qtbase5-dev \
    libcairo2-dev \
    libpoppler-qt5-dev \
    poppler-data \
    && rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* \
    && apt-get -y autoclean

COPY . .

# install npm dependencies and pm2
RUN npm install --only=production && npm install -g pm2

EXPOSE 8080

CMD ["npm", "start"]
```